# Safe to refer to values in outer function from inner function?

Tags: go

I am moving to Go from Node.js and I am concerned whether a construct that I would use in Node is safe to do in Go and whether there is a more idiomatic way to accomplish the same thing.  I am using the Echo framework and want to set a route specific struct that will be available within the context object.  I could generate the struct for every call within middleware, but it's expensive to do so.  Instead, I set the struct once in an outer func that then returns an inner func that refers to the struct in the outer func.  My hope is that I then only incur the generation cost once and then have the correct struct associated with my route for every call.

```
e.POST(path, POST.GenericPostHandler, func(next echo.HandlerFunc)  echo.HandlerFunc {
    operation := getOperationMap(path)
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        c.Set("op", operation)
        return next(c)
    }
})
```

Are there any concerns with this code?  Will it cause problems with GC?  Is there a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing?  I assume a copy of the struct is made every time the middleware is called.

Comment: one of the idiomatic ways is not using a framework https://www.nicolasmerouze.com/build-web-framework-golang/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `operationMap` never changes after initialization, You can declare `operationMap` as a singleton instance like following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var (
    operationMapInst map[string]string // I don't know the exact type of map, so you should change the type.
    operationMapOnce sync.Once
)

func getOperationMap() map[string]string {
    // operationMapOnce.Do() runs only once
    // when the first time getOperationMap() is called.
    operationMapOnce.Do(func() {
        // Initialize operationMapInst.
        operationMapInst = map[string]string{"/": "root", "/ver": "version"}
        fmt.Println("operaionMap has initialized!")
    })

    return operationMapInst
}

func main() {
    // The initialization logic runs only once.
    // Because getOperationMap() returns map,
    // syntax for the value for a path should be getOperationMap()[path],
    // not getOperationMap(path).
    rootOp, ok := getOperationMap()["/"]
    fmt.Println(rootOp, ok)

    // repetition
    rootOp, ok = getOperationMap()["/"]
    fmt.Println(rootOp, ok)
    verOp, ok := getOperationMap()["/ver"]
    fmt.Println(verOp, ok)
    verOp, ok = getOperationMap()["/ver"]
    fmt.Println(verOp, ok)
}
```

You can run this code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/fulBWgEovE).

I recommend http://marcio.io/2015/07/singleton-pattern-in-go/ for understanding singleton pattern in Go.

Comment: Interesting, this was my initial approach.  I stored the additional info using the route method and path as the key for a lookup.  I decided to change it to the middleware approach I described because it seemed "cleaner" and kept the data closer to where it was needed (avoids the lookup cost each time?).  Is there a benefit to the singleton approach vs the middleware approach?

Comment: I think it's a good pattern to use a singleton instance for getOperationMap (or other expensive functions)'s return value whether you use middleware or not. And I agree that using middleware is fine in this situation. I don't think they are mutually exclusive (or versus) things.

Answer (score 1):

This code is safe, won't cause GC problems, and is a good, idiomatic pattern that can be used in Go.

In your example, only one `operation` will be created, moved to the heap, and then shared by each request as they are handled by Echo.

I often use this exact pattern myself when I need to initialize an expensive struct that will be used when handling all requests.

Comment: Do you see benefits to this approach vs. the singleton approach that philipjkim suggests?  Or is it really just a matter of preference?